# Move back to App after launching another App

Tags: android

I have a situation which I have been working on for close to a week now but can not come up with a working solution.

I have an app, which will launch a terminal window and run a command, the terminal used is Jack Palevich's Android-Terminal-Emulator (source code [here](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator)) and the code used to launch a window is:

```
public boolean runCommand(String command) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", command);
    if (mHandle != null) {
        // Identify the targeted window by its handle
        intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.window_handle", mHandle);
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_WINDOW_HANDLE);

    return true;
}
```

Now this works fine, however the issue is that there are a number of times in the apps life that it will need to pass a command to this terminal window, and no user will be interacting with the device (i.e it will need to be automated).

When you launch a terminal window that window becomes the activity in view, therefore while my app still runs in the background any future calls to `runCommand()` will not happen until my app is brought back to view.

So I need to find a way to have my app become the app in view again once it has called `runCommand()` and started the terminal. I have tried a number of routes but with no really success, I guess the only really way forward will be to make changes to the terminal app itself, which I am happy to do (I have the source download and tested) but am just a little stuck as to where to look and what to change.

If you need any more info about my app or anything else, let me know!

Thank you

Comment: If you need persistent communication like that when you may not be foreground you need to have a service.

Comment: Ok so by using a service it would be possible the launch the terminal intent then run another intent to bring my app back into the foreground?

Comment: or another way? just trying to get an idea of how I could do this with a service

Comment: With a service you could just call runCommand() in your service code.