# Launching Intent from service causes crash

Tags: android, android-service

Re: [Move back to App after launching another App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396585/move-back-to-app-after-launching-another-app)

I have now set up a service to run my runCommand() function (see below) however when it comes to actually launching the intent from within run command my app force closes with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime (5448): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-931

E/AndroidRuntime (5448): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActvitiy() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAT_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flas. Is this really what you want?

E/AndroidRuntime (5448): at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:864)

E/AndroidRuntime (5448): at android.content.ContentWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java 276)

E/AndroidRuntime (5448): at packagename.MainService.runCommand(MainService.java:164)
```

So my question is how will I go about launching the required intent form a service?

my service class is:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

boolean copied = false;
private String mHandle;
private static final int REQUEST_WINDOW_HANDLE = 1;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Thread usbUpdateThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {             
            while (true) {
                while (!copied) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(180000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                runCommand("chmod -R 777 /media/cdrom/");
                copied = false; 
            }
        }
    };
    Thread InternetThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3600000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runCommand("php update.php");

            }
        }
    };
    Thread CheckThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(300000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runCommand("sh check.sh");
                }

        }
    };

    InternetThread.start();
    CheckThread.start();
    usbUpdateThread.start();
}


public boolean runCommand(String command) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", command);
    intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.window_handle", MainActivity.mHandle);
    startActivity(intent);


    return true;
}
```

}

And my service is started using:

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
    this.startService(intentService);
```

in my main activity

Comment: paste logcat with a bigger detail

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: You don't launch an intent. You either launch a Service or Activity.

Comment: @A--C yes I have a intent filter set up, the runcommand() worked fine from within the activity class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this flag:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will solve your problem.

```
Intent mInMainAndroidAct= new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
mInMainAndroidAct.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
mInMainAndroidAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mInMainAndroidAct.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", command);
mInMainAndroidAct.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.window_handle", MainActivity.mHandle);
getApplication().startActivity(mInMainAndroidAct);
```