# Launching already running activity from service intent

Tags: android, android-service

RE: [Move back to App after launching another App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396585/move-back-to-app-after-launching-another-app)
and [Launching Intent from service causes crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412846/launching-intent-from-service-causes-crash)

I now have the terminal launching correctly from my service, however my next step is to, after the service has launched the terminal intent to relaunch the apps main activity.

I am doing this using:

```
public void backtoEmplayer(){
    Intent intenti = new Intent(MainService.this,MainActivity.class);
    intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intenti);
}
```

So that it will simply bring forward the main activity which should still be running (As the only two things ever launched on this device will be my app and the terminal).
However when I run the above code I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime (1859): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-931

E/AndroidRuntime (1859): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActvitiy() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAT_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flas. Is this really what you want?

E/AndroidRuntime (1859): at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:864)

E/AndroidRuntime (1859): at android.content.ContentWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java 276)

E/AndroidRuntime (1859): at packagename.MainService.backtoEmplayer(MainService.java:187)
```

What I do not understand is that fact that I am using the FLAT_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag but it still does not work.

My complete service class now looks like:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

    boolean copied = false;
    private String mHandle;
    private static final int REQUEST_WINDOW_HANDLE = 1;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Thread usbUpdateThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {             
                while (true) {
                    while (!copied) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(180000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    runCommand("chmod -R 777 /media/cdrom/");
                    copied = false; 
                }
            }
        };
        Thread InternetThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3600000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        runCommand("php update.php");

                }
            }
        };
        Thread CheckThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(300000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        runCommand("sh check.sh");
try {


Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    backtoEmplayer();
                    }

            }
        };

        InternetThread.start();
        CheckThread.start();
        usbUpdateThread.start();
    }


    public boolean runCommand(String command) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", command);
        intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.window_handle", MainActivity.mHandle);
        startActivity(intent);


        return true;
    }
    public void backtoEmplayer(){


        Intent intenti = new Intent(MainService.this,MainActivity.class);
        intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intenti);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove

```
intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

from your code.

Comment: This works however it spawns a new version of the MainActivity and not the version is already running. My service is started within the onCreate() of the MainActivity, so by removing this flag a new service is started each time we go back to the MainActivity via backtoEmplayer() so thus loops

Comment: Where do you startService in your main activity. This is a quote from the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK document "When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in."

Comment: Yes seem it was another issue and infact removing the flag did work thank you