# Launching already running activity from service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to making lock screen so I made Service class n inside it broadcastReceiver, and MainActivity.
its working till screen is off, whn screen is went on that time main activity close and showing exception.
Please help me to solve it.

MyService.java

```
package com.example.broadcast_receiver;
import android.app.Service;
...

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("[myService]", "onCreate");
        registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("[myService]", "onStart");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("[myService]", "onDestroy");
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");
                Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
            }
        }

    };
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.broadcast_receiver;
import android.os.Bundle;
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("[MainActivity]", "Created");

        try{
        boolean a=isMyServiceRunning();
        if(a==false){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml
(No User Permission added)

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <service android:name="com.example.broadcast_receiver.MyService"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" ></service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcast_receiver.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Please help me to solve dis problem.

Comment: Post your LogCat error.

Comment: Also, what is `context`? A service has its own `context` so you should be able to use `MyService.this`

Comment: @TronicZomB u can see LogCat from below link
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6608612/log.JPG

Comment: @codeMagic i m not using new context, i m using service context only, check that i gave service Context name as context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you can't call `startActivity()` from outside of a `Activity` without setting the `Intent flag NEW_TASK`. Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` TO YOUR `Intent` before calling `startActivity()`

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thnx, i jst found dis solution from another link i.e.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414890/launching-already-running-activity-from-service-intent